# Changing SQL Stored Procedure for multiple search results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some inherited code I need to modify in order to accommodate multiple @ParentFolderID parameter. At present, one ID is passed in. However I will now need to account for several ID's being passed in and returning results from each. Below is the current code. I'm not quite sure what exactly where I would start.

```
declare @Values             xml
declare @ValueAttributeID   int
declare @YearAttributeID    int
declare @CategoryID         int
declare @year               int
declare @ParentFolderID     int
declare @DealerAttributeID  int

set @ParentFolderID = 10646615
set @CategoryID = 10646175
set @YearAttributeID = 3
set @ValueAttributeID = 2
set @year = 2014
set @Values = '<values><value id=''1000104'' /></values>'

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

with Parents 
(
    dataid
)
as
(
    select            @ParentFolderID

    Union

    select            child.dataid
    from        DTree parent (NOLOCK)
    inner join  DTree child (NOLOCK) 
            on                parent.dataid           = child.parentid
    where       parent.dataid           = @ParentFolderID
    and child.subtype = 0

)
select      doc.name as '@name',
            doc.dataId as '@id',
            (
                select      allAtts.AttrID as '@id',
                            case when ((allAtts.ValInt is null) and (allAtts.ValStr is null))
                                then cast(allAtts.ValDate as nvarchar(255))
                                 when (allAtts.ValInt is null and allAtts.ValDate is null)
                                then cast(allAtts.ValStr as nvarchar(255))
                                 when (allAtts.ValDate is null and allAtts.ValStr is null)
                                then cast(allAtts.ValInt as nvarchar(255))
                            end as '@val'
                from        LLAttrData allAtts (NOLOCK) 
                where       allAtts.id = doc.dataid
                for xml path('attribute'), TYPE         
            )

from        DTree category (NOLOCK)


inner join  LLAttrData value (NOLOCK) 
on          category.dataid = value.defid

--Changes per environment (value attribute)
and         value.AttrID            = @ValueAttributeID

--Check for values
inner join @Values.nodes('//value') as A(att)
on          A.att.value('@id', 'nvarchar(255)') = value.ValStr

--Changes per environment (year attribute)
inner join  LLAttrData y (NOLOCK) 
on          category.dataid = y.defid

--Changes per environment (year attribute)
and         y.AttrID                = @YearAttributeID

--Check for year
and         year(y.valDate)         = @year

inner join  DTree doc (NOLOCK)
on          value.id    = doc.dataid
and         y.id        = doc.dataid


inner join  Parents parent
on          parent.dataid   = doc.parentid

--Must be associated to the  category
where       category.dataid = @CategoryID -- This is the hard coded category ID

order by doc.dataid --, allAtts.AttrID 

FOR XML PATH('document'), Root('documents')`
```

Comment: Hi you have a couple things going on here. It seems you have a procedure that works for a single ID. When you need to pass in multiples you have a couple of ways to handle that. One option is to pass in a table valued parameter. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx. Another way to deal with this is to pass in a delimited string. But for that you will also need a decent splitter. http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings

Comment: As a side note, you seem to be using the NOLOCK all over the place here. There are some very serious issues that hint brings to the table that you need to absolutely certain you are ok with. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/ And if you are going to use any hints you MUST include the WITH keyword. Leaving it off for hints is deprecated and will stop working at some point in the future.

Comment: doesn't `SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;`  make every select `NOLOCK`?

Comment: @JamieD77 yes it is the same thing. I guess the original developer REALLY want to be sure that the data is inconsistent.

Comment: How is the list of IDs going to be passed in?

Comment: @SteveMangiameli a string is passed in now from a c# web service call.

Comment: By the way this all great advice I will look at. I am more comfortable in C# than SQL. But really just wanted to see if changing the SQL or the C# web service call was a better option here, based on amount of effort and time.

Comment: If you are more comfortable in C# then I would just loop the call passing in one string at a time and leave your stored procedure alone.  That seems like it would be less work, for you.  If you have to do this on the SQL side, I'd still leave the basic functionality of this SP alone, fixing the nolock hints etc,  and create another procedure to parse the IDs and pass them into the existing SP.